# Save attachment from an email in to a folder that changes every month

Tags: vba, outlook

i 'm trying to get a VBA macro in Outlook that will save an email's attachment to a specific folder (that changes every month) and add the YYYYMM of prior month received to the file name.

The outlook rule identifies that an email header contains 'NTMR' from a person.

And when it does so, it runs the script where it saves the attachment in a folder.

So when the macro identifies the month of the email received, it saves in the folder that is one month behind. For instance:

email received on DD/04/17 as 'Here is the NTMR file for you', it will save the file in a folder within 201703 parent folder as NTMR - 201703

So the path of the file will be C:\Users\alitalh\Downloads\Test\201703\Source Files\NTMR 201703

I have come up with the follownig macro - please advise as To how i can fix it?

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim dateFormat As String
    saveFolder = "C:\Users\alitalh\Downloads\Test"
    dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyymm" - 1, 1)

    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & "\" & "Source Files" & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName & dateFormat
        Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

how can i strip out the NTMR from the header and put it in the filename?

I have another macro that sets up the folder prior to the email so we don't need to create another folder

Comment: Where is the NTMR? Subject line? Or email body?

Comment: @0m3r subject line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Work with **[MSDN Split Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx)***

*Example on your Subject line **`Here is the NTMR file for you`** split it by space character **`(" ")`***

*Code Example*

```
Sub Example()
    Dim Item As Outlook.mailitem

    Set Item = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

    Debug.Print Item.subject ' Print on Immediate Window (Ctrl+G)

    Item.subject = Split(Item.subject, " ")(3)

    Debug.Print Item.subject ' Print on Immediate Window (Ctrl+G)

End Sub
```

*Your subject = **`(Here)(1)`** **`(is)(2)`** **`(the)(3)`** **`(NTMR)(4)`** **`(file)(5)`** **`(for)(6)`** **`(you)(7)`***

*Now **`Split(subject line), "space")(3)`** While assigning to string variable*

```
Dim FileName As String
FileName = Split(Item.subject, " ")(3)
```

*Replace **`objAtt.DisplayName`** with **`FileName`***

---

```
Dim FileName As String
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & _
                       dateFormat & "\" & _
                    "Source Files" & "\" & FileName & dateFormat
Next
```

> *<sub>By default, or when Limit equals -1, the Split function splits the input string at every occurrence of the delimiter string, and returns the **substrings** in an array. 
>
>   When the Limit parameter is greater than zero, the Split function splits the string at the first **Limit-1** occurrences of the delimiter, and returns an array with the resulting substrings. 
>
>   For example, **`Split("a:b:c", ":") returns the array {"a", "b", "c"}`**, 
>
>   while **`Split("a:b:c", ":", 2) returns the array {"a", "b:c"}`**.</sub>*
>
> ---

*To get previous month try **[DateAdd Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcxe65wz(v=vs.90).aspx)***

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim PrevMonth As String

    PrevMonth = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "yyyymm")
    Debug.Print PrevMonth
End Sub
```

> *<sub>Some useful date functions worth exploring in other contexts include **`DateDiff`**, **`DatePart`**, **`DateSerial`**, Day, Month, Year, and **`IsDate`**.
>   **`IsDate`** (which checks whether a string is a valid date) is particularly useful for things like `UserForms` where you may want to force the user to type a valid date into a certain textbox.</sub>*
>
> ---

Comment: thank you so much.. will the dateFormat work fine in my code?

Comment: how can i make my dateFormat get a month prior to current month?

Comment: @wasimakram101 just the month and the year?-

Comment: yes, in YYYYMM format. That's what im having an issue with. Thank you so much for taking the time out for this.