# Outlook VBA How can I save attached files automatically

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have a question about the Outlook macro.

I would like to create a macro like below, but would anyone know if anyone knows a better way?

Purpose: Extract e-mail with attached file from received e-mail, create folder locally, save attached file and e-mail itself

means:
1, Macro start. Extract mail with attached file of specific folder such as inbox
2, (When there is a mail with attached file) Create a folder (in a specific folder) with the folder name "Date_title of e-mail" and save the attached file and the e-mail with the attached file. Do the same work for mails with all attached files and end the macro.
3, (when there is no mail with attached file) finish macro

I try to use following macro.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Save-attachments-from-5b6bf54b

I attempted to save the attached file using the macro above.
Although it worked well, all attached files are saved in one folder, I can not create the operation of creating a folder for each attached mail and saving it separately.
Does anyone know how to deal with it?

Best,

Comment: There are *dozens* of examples and instructions of how to do this available online.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save attachment from an email in to a folder that changes every month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43640609/save-attachment-from-an-email-in-to-a-folder-that-changes-every-month), or see [**Rule to automatically save attachment in Outlook**](https://www.pixelchef.net/content/rule-autosave-attachment-outlook) and several [**others here**](https://www.google.com/search?q=outlook+rules+%22save+attachment%22+folder).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are almost there.  Add in this little line of code, and adjust to suit your needs.

MkDir "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Downloads\" & " " & Format$(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") & " " & Format$(Time, "hh-mm-ss")