# How to automatically save an attachment, with overwrite?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to extract an Excel report from an Outlook email, and save it in a folder called "OLAttachments" in my Documents folder.

I also need it to overwrite the previous day's file. These email attachments have the same name each day.

This is what I have so far. Each time the email comes through, it saves a new file, whereas I would like to overwrite the existing file.

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String
sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\fmustapha\Documents\Outlook Attachments"
For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
    oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: See [Save attachment from an email in to a folder that changes every month](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43640609/4088852). For the record, you "code" or "write" VBA as opposed to "personalize" it.

Comment: Are you trying to save it on today's date?

Comment: No, I'm just trying to save it a generic file name "New Members" and have it replace the file with the previous day's data. So everyday it would just replace. Would this be an issue? Will it always prompt you to clarify whether you wanted to replace the existing file? Because if so, I'm okay with saving it as "New Members MM-DD-YYYY"

Comment: "I also need it to overwrite the previous day's file because these email attachments have the same name each day." is the usual behaviour. Is DisplayName the same each time?

Answer (score 3):

I do this on my server, I receive an email each night that has an Excel file attached, that auto forwards to my server where this outlook code saves off the attachment. Note there is a clause in there to make sure the file comes from me and to make sure it's an Excel file:

```
Private WithEvents olItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub olItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim NewMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Atts As Attachments
    Dim Att As Attachment
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strName As String

    If Item.Class = olMail Then
       Set NewMail = Item
    End If
    strPath = "C:\Reporting Archive\Sales Files\"
    If NewMail.Sender = "Dan Donoghue" Then

       Set Atts = Item.Attachments

       If Atts.Count > 0 Then
          For Each Att In Atts
              If InStr(LCase(Att.FileName), ".xls") > 0 Then Att.SaveAsFile strPath & Att.FileName
          Next
       End If
    End If
End Sub
```

It goes in `ThisOutlookSession` in the VBE, once you have put it in close and reopen outlook and it will work.

To save over the top I would recommend you delete the existing file first (you can use the `kill` command for this then simply save the new one).

You would do that by replacing this:

```
If InStr(LCase(Att.FileName), ".xls") > 0 Then Att.SaveAsFile strPath & Att.FileName
```

with this:

```
If InStr(LCase(Att.FileName), ".xls") > 0 Then
    Kill strPath & Att.FileName
    Att.SaveAsFile strPath & Att.FileName
End If
```

in my code

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a rule that triggers this job in any frequency you want (you probably don't want the rule to run in seconds, but more like 1x per day, overnight, etc.)

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String
sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\DT168\Documents\outlook-attachments\"
For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
Next
End Sub
```

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/3747-outlook-auto-download-save-attachments-to-folder.html#a1

Answer (score 0):

*Try using [Date function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/date-function) Which Returns a Variant (Date) containing the current system date. MSDN*

Example

**`oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & "New Members" & " " & Format(Date - 1, "MM-DD-YYYY")`**

Comment: Thank you so much! I'd really prefer to overwrite the file but I can definitely cater to this format... I appreciate it!